# mod URL rewrite is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect, friendly-url

http://www.example.com/index.php?page=property_submit&edit=1&pid=978

I want to rewrite this url to

http://www.example.com/index/property_submit/1/978

**I tried to rewrite by using below code but it is not working:**

```
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?$1=$1

RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?$1=$1 [QSA]
```

Full code follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?$1=$1
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?$1=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: And "is not working" means _what_? Do you get an error in your log files? Is it rewriting to a wrong location? Does the universe implode?

Comment: the url is not changing ..still showing old url

Comment: And what about your log files? Any entry in your http servers error logs?

Comment: there is no error logs produced

Comment: RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?$1=$1
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?$1=$1 [QSA]

Comment: above is the full code

Comment: BTW: what do you mean: "there is no error logs produced" - Certainly your http server _does_ have an error log file. Are you really sure you _did_ look in there?

Comment: Jithu, if you are stuck with solutions below, try turning on `mod_rewrite` logging. It is turned off by default for performance reasons, but turning it on can help show where it is getting stuck. If you do this, don't forget to show us your logs, so someone can advise where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to work on the raw request to handle redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+)&edit=(\d+)&pid=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$ /index.php?page=$1&edit=$2&pid=$3 [L]
```

Comment: it is very sad to say guys ..nothing is working on my site

Comment: could you please help me atleast  on this simple url

Comment: @JithuJohnson Is mod-rewrite loaded in apache? The rules above will work only for URLs like: `http://www.example.com/index.php?page=abc_wxyz&edit=xxx&pid=YYY`

Comment: @JithuJohnson Which page are you visiting, what is being shown, what happens? Do you have access to `httpd.conf` or `vhosts.conf` file for server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern does not match the url you want to rewrite.

Consider this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/property_submit/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=property_submit&edit=$1&pid=$2 [L]
```

I think matching against the 'property_submit' string makes your strategy more safe, since you do not match arbitrary urls you may *not* want to rewrite.

Comment: @JithuJohnson I was still working on the pattern. Sure you tried the current version?

Comment: Sorry, the rule is fine and works for me when I try with your example URL above. I assume your real URLs are different somehow.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement,

http://www.example.com/index.php?page=property_submit&edit=1&pid=978

I want to rewrite this url to

http://www.example.com/index/property_submit/1/978

try below code,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&edit=$2&pid=$3
```